# Liferay installed but localhost:8080 return "No data received"

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, liferay

I have downloaded liferay bundle with tomcat.
I unpack it to my mac `Applications/Administrating/liferay....`
I have run `./startup.sh` 
And at the exnd I get: `INFO: Server startup in 47781 ms`
But when I open `localhost:8080` in browser I get `"No data received"` like there is no site installed.
This is whole log:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
STSiMacVVU:bin vladimirvucetic$ tail -f ../logs/catalina.out 
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 665 ms
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
Loading jar:file:/Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Loading jar:file:/Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:30:21,037 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for HSQL Database Engine 2
14:30:21,040 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:86] Liferay is configured to use Hypersonic as its database. Do NOT use Hypersonic in production. Hypersonic is an embedded database useful for development and demo'ing purposes. The database settings can be changed in portal-ext.properties.
14:30:21,084 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
14:30:36,629 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][PDFProcessorImpl:235] Liferay is not configured to use ImageMagick. For better quality document and image previews, install ImageMagick and enable it in portal-ext.properties or in the Server Administration control panel at: http://<server>/group/control_panel/manage/-/server/external-services
Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.2 CE (Paton / Build 6102 / August 2, 2013)
14:30:41,605 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:478] Database supports case sensitive queries
14:30:42,056 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][ServerDetector:169] Server supports hot deploy
14:30:42,064 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][PluginPackageUtil:1046] Reading plugin package for the root context
14:30:44,914 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][AutoDeployDir:144] Auto deploy scanner started for /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/deploy
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Remoting Servlet'
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/marketplace-portlet
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/portal-compat-hook
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/resources-importer-web
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/Administrating/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/welcome-theme
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 47781 ms
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you getting blank page on localhost:8080?

Comment: Yes I get blank page when I try to access localhost:8080

Comment: I had faced same issue. I am not sure but it was issue with virtual host setting. localhost:8080/web/guest/home would work if you try..

Comment: No that doesn't work also :(

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is to check if tomcat is receiving requests on port 8080 ; in your command-line type:

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

If you get a black/empty screen then tomcat is indeed listening on that port, otherwise you get a connection failure, then you need to doublecheck you tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Liferay started up normally (but add more information - catalina.out or others, as gamerson requested in a comment)

Also:

- Check Firewall settings (8080 might be blocked)
- Your lsof output lists IPV6 (it's been long since I interpreted lsof
  output and commandline - this might be normal, or not. You don't say
  if you attempt an IPV4 connection)
- Try to connect with a browser from that server. If it's a shell-only
  server, use w3m or lynx on `http://localhost:8080/`

  #user  nobody;
      worker_processes  1;

  ```
  events {
      worker_connections  1024;
  }


  http {
      passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5;
      passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1;
      passenger_max_pool_size 10;
      include       mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      sendfile        on;
      keepalive_timeout  65;

      gzip  on;

      server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log /var/www/access.log;
        error_log  /var/www/error.log;

       location / {
          root   /var/www/demo/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
          rails_env production;
       }

       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
          root   html;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: why am I seeing my answer copy-pasted here!!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured a connector port 8080 so you won't get a response. The only connector you have configured is for AJP on port 8009 as can be seen from the logs.

```
Oct 21, 2013 2:30:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: I don't understand what should I do. If I try localhost:8009 I get in log: org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245

Comment: In tomcat-conf-server.xml I have: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />

Comment: Are you sure that file is being used? Are you sure that connector isn't commented out? That connector configuration isn't being read for some reason otherwise it would appear in the logs.

Comment: Yes and it's not commented. I install liferay for the first time on linux it works but in osx same installation doesnt. Any idea what could be important to check again?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the server from Eclipse, Go to Servers -> ports and set 8080 for HTTP/1.1
[image]

If you're running a standalone Tomcat, go and edit tomcat/conf/server.xml and set

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Make sure that the port 8080 is allowed from the server, and it's not used from another application
When the Server start, you should be able to read in the log this :

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: "...and it's not used from another application" how I can check this in osx?

Comment: in linux, it's 'sudo netstat -tnlp' , I guess it should work in osx too

Comment: However, I think that you have your server.xml file with a wrong port. Are you sure you're editing the right server.xml file ?

Comment: I have unpacked the liferay bundle and go to that directory > tomcat > conf > server.xml so I am sure that this is the right file :(

Comment: please, scan your server.xml for the string '8009' and tell about the matching uncommented xml nodes you can find

Answer (score 0):

My expectation would be to find this in the log:

```
24.10.2013 13:43:14 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
24.10.2013 13:43:14 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

this would indicate the protocol handler for 8080 to start.

My advice to find the root cause of your problem is:

- Access `localhost:8080` *before* you start Liferay. This might give you the same result, indicating that there's some other software running on port 8080.
- If this didn't help: Download a Liferay tomcat bundle again, unzip unchanged to a new location, run that one unchanged as well - if this one works, compare both directories, especially tomcat's `/conf/` directory.
- If that doesn't work, check if your environment defines any of the variables CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE, LIFERAY_HOME.
- You'll be able to see more of the logs that you posted by running just a single command like `./bin/catalina.sh run`. This will run tomcat in the foreground, showing the logs from the beginning without the chance to miss something because the `tail` command came too late

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some other process using port 8080. Check it with this command:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep ':8080'
```

Kill that running process

```
sudo kill -9 {PID}
```

For example

```
sudo kill -9 1234
```

Restart Tomcat (if installed as service)

```
service tomcat7 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly had a environment variable for CATALINA_HOME setup a few months back pointing to a different tomcat setup this caused the port 8080 to be invoked by that older setup and thus getting reserved before its used by Liferay. Make sure your CATALINA_HOME variable is configured to point at the tomcat bundled with Liferay.